# Custom variables in Visual Studio Code settings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following settings in my `settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/bin/python3.6",
    "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/path/to/bin/yapf",
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "/path/to/bin/python3.6",
    }
}
```

What I'd like to have is something like:

```
{
    "venvPath": "/path/to/venv",
    "python.pythonPath": "${venvPath}/bin/python3.6",
    "python.formatting.yapfPath": "${venvPath}/bin/yapf",
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "${python.pythonPath}",
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as it stands there is no support for use of environment variables like that (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2809)). In the mean time I would suggest a .bat file that to write your *settings.json* file with your desired path. For your example you could do something like this:

```
set venvPath=/path/to/venv
echo {> settings.json
echo     "python.pythonPath": "%venvPath%/bin/python3.6",>> settings.json
echo     "python.formatting.yapfPath": "%venvPath%/bin/yapf",>>settings.json
echo     "code-runner.executorMap": {>> settings.json
echo         "python": "${python.pythonPath}",>> settings.json
echo     }>> settings.json
echo }>> settings.json
```

This will create the following *settings.json* file

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/path/to/venv/bin/python3.6",
    "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/path/to/venv/bin/yapf",
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "${python.pythonPath}",
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW The issue that you linked to is actually on its way of getting done (check out the latest comments).